# An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '\package.json' me marca error al hacer ng build --prod

Tags: nodejs, angular

[image: Este es el error]

Me marca este error al intentar hacer el empaquetado de producción, ya probé en otra maquina y pude hacerlo sin problemas con el mismo repositorio, ya desinstale todo y lo volví a instalar, probé varias versiones de node, npm y angular y aun no se porque pasa.
El package.json se encuentra en la carpeta raíz y todo esta como en la otra computadora que si lo corrió. No entiendo que pasara.
Cabe mencionar que el ng serve me corre sin problemas.

La estructura de mi proyecto es la siguiente...

[image: Estructura]

Me sale el siguiente error al hacer el ng build --configuratioon=prod y si cuento con el enviroment de producción en mi angular.json

[image: Error]

Ya con el npm run build --prod me genero el compilado sin problemas, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Puedes mostrar la estructura de carpetas de tu proyecto?

Comment: Ya la subí, la carpeta dist no tiene nada, solo la cree.

Comment: Hola, puedes mostrar lo que tienes en package.json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes simplemente correr: `npm run build --prod` o

En el package.json en la parte de scripts puedes crearte un comando nuevo así:

`build-prod`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando vayas a compilar pones: `npm run build-prod` si no quieres agregar la configuración puedes correr solo `ng build --configuration=production` . Esto te va a funcionar si tienes un archivo de ambiente para producción y este se encuentre registrado en tu angular.json de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, si lo intente y cheque mi configuración del angular.json pero me marca el error que subi.

Comment: Corriste este comando: npm run build --prod y te sigue diciendo lo mismo? para que te funcione ng build --configuration=production debes tener esa configuración en tu angular.json y también el archivo enviroment.production.ts creado.

Comment: Ya con el npm run build --prod me genero el compilado sin problemas, muchisimas gracias.