# Environment externo en ionic

Tags: angular, ionic

Buenas a todos… actualmente estoy trabajando en una aplicación ionic/angular. Esta aplicación sería la misma para muchos clientes solo cambiará los datos que tengo en el enviroment como la api a consultar… mi duda es la siguiente hay alguna forma de coger el archivo enviroment de forma externa. Es decir desde una carpeta externa al proyecto donde yo cree un enviroment.ts y este sea llamado desde la aplicación. Así solo tendría que cambiar este archivo para cada cliente sin tener necesidad de modificar el código.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes tener varios archivos de enviroments:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tu package.json configuras varios comandos (build-client-1, build-client-2) para que sea más fácil al momento de compilar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si quieres compilar para el cliente 1 corres `npm run build-client-1`. Si no quieres crear los comandos puedes correr directamente `npm run build --configuration=client-1`.

Si decides crear los comandos, esta respuesta puede ser útil: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/557913/95248

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo

Comment: Esta respuesta puede ser útil como guía pero ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor edítala para añadir más detalles: ¿Cómo se seleccionaría un environment u otro dependiendo del cliente? ¿Cuál sería el código y dónde iría? Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: Respuesta editada.